# OpenCV in iOS not decoding frames properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV on iOS to do some pixel analysis on video frames. I've tried several .MOV files (all MPEG-4 AVC) but none of them seem to decode properly.

Problems:
- All cvGetCaptureProperty calls return a value of 1
- cvGrabFrame(capture) always returns true (it doesn't seem to find the last frame)

Things that are actually working
- Frame height and width are correctly determined

Any ideas? I have OpenCV 2.3.2 from http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/

```
    NSURL *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sky" withExtension:@"MOV"];

    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromFile([[file path] UTF8String]);
    if (!capture)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error loading file");
        return;
    }

    cvQueryFrame(capture);

    int width = cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    int height = cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    NSLog(@"dimensions = %dx%d", width, height); // returns 1x1

    double framesPerSecond = cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    NSLog(@"framesPerSecond = %f", framesPerSecond); // returns 1

    int frameCount = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    NSLog(@"frameCount = %d", frameCount); // returns 1

    int frameCounter = 0;

    while (cvGrabFrame(capture))
    {
        frameCounter++;

        //NSLog(@"got a frame! %d", frameCounter);

        if (frameCounter % 50 == 0)
        {
            IplImage* frame = cvRetrieveFrame(capture);

            NSLog(@"frame width: %d", frame->width); // works correctly
            NSLog(@"frame height: %d", frame->height); // works correctly
        }

        if (frameCounter > 1000)
            break; // this is here because the loop never stops on its own

    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

Comment: Could you test changing the return type to double.  e.g. `double frameCount = cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);`  I don't know if it'll help and I don't have my opencv environment available to check where I am.  The docs do state double as the return type though.

Comment: I'll try and look at this for you, I'm no opencv expert but I do find it an interesting set of tools and have abused it in the past.

Comment: I've poked and prodded using the same framework build as you and as far as I can tell you are experiencing the same bugs as many other users (search for them, linux users especially).  Having said that I do have my own build from an old project and I'll check that later.

Comment: My build at home won't even open video files! :/

Comment: FWIW, I'm getting identical results a year later.